# Are there any unique bows whose enchantments make them a better choice than a custom enchanted bow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a definitive 'Best Weapon' for each weapon type in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42686/is-there-a-definitive-best-weapon-for-each-weapon-type-in-skyrim)

*Inspired by [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42749/4797) on the ["Is there a definitive 'Best Weapon' for each weapon type in Skyrim?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42686/is-there-a-definitive-best-weapon-for-each-weapon-type-in-skyrim) question*:

Are there any unique bows whose enchantments make them a better choice than a custom enchanted bow?

Comment: Isn't this question explicitly part of that question? Wouldn't any answers here also belong there? Wouldn't this do better merged with that, as a single weapon guide? I _think_ the answer to all these is yes, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @disinter I believe I'm asking a different and more specific question (only *unique bows' enchantments*, specifically). Notice that no answer in that question talked about *bows*. If you checked out the answer I linked to, it suggested a 'better' question - and my question here is inspired by that. Also, this is not a call for a discussion unlike that question, as [mentioned there by Bora](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42686/is-there-a-definitive-best-weapon-for-each-weapon-type-in-skyrim#comment61779_42686).

Comment: @James I don't see why this question is a "duplicate". (See my reply to disinter.)

Comment: @disinter To answer your questions: 1.) Maybe. But according to Bora regarding that question: "*Your question seems to call for a discussion, which is not desired on this site. If you could be more specific, the answers will possibly help the community.*" This question is not a call for discussion, and is more specific.  
2.) Maybe. That question is too broad, though. I reckon it would be better to ask for questions that are specific and does not call for a discussion.

Comment: @disinter 3.) No. Because the question there is faulty and seems to be calling for a discussion, while my question is not and is more specific. (I worded my question so that it won't sound like it's asking for a discussion, and to be more specific, so that the community can give better answers.)

Comment: My answer to that question doesn't mention bows because there aren't any with unique properties that bear mentioning. Just as there are no maces. Aside from some [unique considerations regarding weight in the crafting of a custom bow](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49789/skyrim-bows-light-or-heavy-one), nothing you'll find in that answer is invalid.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I see. I'm not saying your answer there is invalid, though. I thought the people who answered that question just forgot about the bows. =)

Comment: @galacticninja and I'm telling you that I didn't *forget* bows, but that there isn't anything particularly special about bows that requires that they get extra attention in that question.

Comment: @desaivv The Nightingale Bow is, functionally, just an Ebony bow with Frost damage and Shock damage enchantments. You can easily craft one of your own, so it doesn't fit the criteria OP is asking for.

Comment: @desaivv In addition to what LessPop says, the Nightingale Bow has no smithing perks (despite being ebony). So it's [actually quite easy to smith a better bow](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48042/how-much-can-i-improve-the-nightingale-bow/48053#48053), and the same is true for enchantments.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I realized that when I read your comment to your answer in the "Is there a definitive 'Best Weapon' for each weapon type in Skyrim?" question. (I first just scanned for the answers, and no one mentioned bows.) Anyways, maybe that is the answer to this question? ("...there isn't anything particularly special about bows that requires that they get extra attention ...") I still believe that the initial commenters to this question's reason for closing are invalid.

Comment: I see nothing that distinguishes this question from the other, except for its specificity.  Therefore, it *is* a duplicate.  If there's not a satisfactory answer addressing part of the other question, post a bounty to it.

Comment: @galacticninja I'm one of the close votes. There is nothing about this question that will provide any new or interesting information that is not already found in the other question. It *is* a duplicate. It's a *good* duplicate (in the sense that it's the sort we want around for it's google value, and it shouldn't be deleted), but it should still be closed in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, especially if you intend to use the Smithing>Enchanting>Smithing exploit to make an incredible weapon, but the Nightingale Bow does come relatively close. If you're lacking in enchanting or smithing skill, this is a valid option to replace leveling these skills just for that reason.

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nightingale_Bow