# Where can I find bows with rare or unique enchantments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As we all know there are weapons that look unique and have unique enchantments. I however, have not found a single unique weapon that is a bow.

There is the bow that you get from the Thieves' Guild quest line, but I'm talking about bows that you won't get from a quest line; for example, I was wandering around in a cave once and found a sword with the paralyze enchantment. This must have been unique because this enchantment is hard to get your hands on and it was found at a certain location. I'm hoping to find some bows that have cool enchantments and looks too.

Are there bows that are found outside of quest lines that have unique or rare enchantments? Where can I find them?

Comment: Related: [Are there any unique bows whose enchantments make them a better choice than a custom enchanted bow?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53266/3389) and [Is there a definitive 'Best Weapon' for each weapon type in Skyrim?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42686/3389).

Answer (score 7):

The only truly unique bow I know of is the Bow of the Hunt, which has a unique enchantment (+20 damage to all animals) and it can be found in [Clearspring Cave](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Clearspring_Cave)

If you have the Dawnguard DLC, you can obtain Auriel's bow, which is a bow with a rather unique effect.

There is also a [list on the wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Unique_Weapons_(Skyrim)) for unique bows that always appear in a particular spot in the game.  Note most of them are unique due to its name only, their enchantments and looks can be duplicated.

Comment: The name could be duplicated too, during enchanting ;)

Comment: @kotekzot great point

Answer (score 2):

A good bow is the [Dwarven Black Bow of Fate](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Dwarven_Black_Bow_of_Fate) but you will need the Dragonborn DLC. Get these gems that open the gates in [Kagrumez](http://uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Kagrumez). When you are there you can find two but you need four. You can buy one from the man near the strider to the east and then south. Another can be found in the questline or just going to a Dwarven ruin. After that do the puzzles and YAY - Dwarven Black Bow of Fate. It gives a 50% chance of absorbing health, stamina and/or magic.

Answer (score 0):

Keep visiting The Drunken Huntsman in Whiterun. He often sells enchanted bows.

Answer (score -1):

Auriels bow is the best bow I have found so far. Though you have to have dawn guard it is on the main quest line. You obtain it by an auctally snow elf. If you are interested look it up online. It also come with two different types of arrows.

Comment: Please don't just say look it up online.  That's the whole point of what we do here.